# Redirect in based on cookie and prevent loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, cookies

I am trying to redirect if cookie is not set with `htaccess`, but I can't prevent the redirection loop.

It's for wordpress installation.

Here is my `.htaccess` at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^cookie_name[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_to_redirect/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /page_to_redirect/ [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Try with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name [NC]`, without `^` and add one space, because your cookie is not necessarily the first.

Comment: Redirection loop persist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - if the cookie is set, the request isn't a file or directory, the request will be handled by **index.php**, otherwise it will be handled by **redirect.php**, which should presumably set the cookie.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie_name [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule .* /redirect.php [L]
```